# Regex in JMeter is not possible

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have following request samplers (dynamic values included) in my JMeter test case,

[image]
[image]

I have tried regular expression method using Regular Expression Extractor plugin in my test case and till now the result is failed. The regular expression myself mentioned in the test case is,

```
"authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"
```

But it won't works, So can anyone please give a solution for this. For reference I have mentioned the regex results for the post data.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your response from where you need to extract the value and then update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Jahan Please verify the above screen shots, That is my actual response for regex

Comment: I've already checked those screenshots and you're showing request body not the response! Provide a response body of a request from where you want to extract something! Also, mention which portion you want to extract from that response.

Answer (score 1):

Check the previous request, before login, from where your script should get the token.
You may use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener while recording this script and see, where is you get this token and test your RegExp in this response with XPath Tester view.

Check [Authentication Using JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/test-rest-apis-authentication-using-jmeter/) guide to get additional information.